# add web page in xamarin form

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm very very new to using Xamarin forms. So new in fact I have just watched the "microsoft xamarin forms for absolute beginners".

I'm trying to include a webpage into the Xamarin form but the only info I can find is

```
var browser = new WebView {
    Source = "http://xamarin.com"
};
```

This might sound silly but has anyone got a full tutorial on how to include one?

thanks

Comment: I would start by downloading the project from the page that you got that code sample and begin by playing with it: https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/WorkingWithWebview/

Answer (score 1):

just create a WebView and assign it to a ContentPage.  Then you can either make this page the main page of your app (in the App class) or you can navigate to it from another page.

```
ContentPage page = new ContentPage {
  Content = new WebView { Source = "http://xamarin.com" }
};
```

Comment: Is it really that simple? thanks I will give that a try, and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

To display a website from the internet, set the WebView's Source property to a string URL:

```
var browser = new WebView
{
  Source = "http://xamarin.com"
};
```

see this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=windows#performance